# Why isn't this method being overridden?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In a project of mine I encountered this problem where the polymorphism seemingly doesn't work. Derived classes don't seem to override the base class, but no errors ocurr either.

This is a simplification of the code, but it generates the same problem. The usage of `vector` and `unique_ptr` is the same as in my project, I suspect that my usage of those is what's causing the problem.

I expect

```
void print() override 
{ 
    printf("B HEJ");
}
```

to override

```
virtual void print() 
{ 
    printf("A HEJ"); 
}
```

, but it doesn't. Why?

Here is the complete source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void print() 
    { 
        printf("A HEJ"); 
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void print() override { printf("B HEJ"); }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> ass;
    ass.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>(B()));
    ass[0]->print();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Remember, `make_unique` makes a new *object* too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `make_unique<B>` *and* add a `virtual` destructor to the base class.

- `make_unique<B>` creates a `unique_ptr<B>` that, if `B` is derived from `A` will be accepted by (moved into) a `unqiue_ptr<A>`.
- `make_unique<A>(B())` copy constructs an `A` from a `B`, slicing the `B` (only the `A` part of the default constructed `B` will be copied).
- As long as the `virtual` method chain is preserved, the most derived method is called. Not having a `virtual` destructor makes sure that only the base class destructor is called when you have a `vector` of base class pointers. The result is more often than not catastrophic. You want the destructor(s) of the most derived classes to be called - so make the base class destructor `virtual`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    
    virtual void print() 
    { 
        printf("A HEJ"); 
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void print() override { printf("B HEJ"); }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> ass;
    ass.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>());
    ass[0]->print();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You have an error here:

```
 ass.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>(B()));
```

This line creates a unique pointer to `A`, initializing it by copying from default-constructed `B`. It is equivalent with `new A(B())` for naked pointers.

You need to create a unique pointer to `B`, so your code should look like:

```
 ass.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>());
```

While on it, do not forget to add virtual destructor to `A`.